# Return First Non Zero Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

My desired result set is

```
Red  Purple
 1     5
```

all on **one row**.

My query below returns 4 rows.
What would be the syntax to only return 1 row?

```
DECLARE @BlueBonnet TABLE (
    randarfield FLOAT
    ,confis VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO @BlueBonnet (randarfield, confis)
VALUES('0.00', 'red'), ('0.00','red'), ('0.00','blue'), ('0.00','blue')
    , ('0.00','purple'), ('5.00','purple'), ('0.00','orange')
    , ('1.00','red'), ('0.00','blue'), ('0.00','blue')

SELECT Red  = CASE WHEN confis = 'red' THEN MAX(randarfield) ELSE 0 END
    ,Purple = CASE WHEN confis = 'purple' THEN MAX(randarfield) ELSE 0 END
FROM @BlueBonnet
GROUP BY confis
```

Comment: You say that you want the first result, but how are the results supposed to be ordered? Is there a missing IDENTITY column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options here:

In keeping with your **`MAX`**:

```
SELECT
     MAX(CASE WHEN confis = 'red'    THEN randarfield END) AS Red
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN confis = 'purple' THEN randarfield END) AS Purple
FROM @BlueBonnet
```

But if you really want the **first** (not the max):

```
SELECT
 (SELECT TOP 1 randarfield FROM @BlueBonnet WHERE randarfield>0 AND confis = 'red'   ) Red
,(SELECT TOP 1 randarfield FROM @BlueBonnet WHERE randarfield>0 AND confis = 'purple') Purple
```

Though depending on your definition of "first" you would need to add an `ORDER BY ...` to the two subqueries for whatever column you order by to decide what is first.

Answer (score 2):

As many people have already mentioned, it depends on if you need **The First**, **The Min** or **The Max**.

Here is a solution using **`IDENTITY`**, **better test data**, **`PIVOT`** and **`ROW_NUMBER()`**:

```
DECLARE @BlueBonnet TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) --I added an IDENTITY field!
    ,randarfield FLOAT
    ,confis VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO @BlueBonnet (randarfield, confis)
VALUES('0.00', 'red'), ('0.00','red'), ('0.00','blue'), ('0.00','blue')
    , ('0.00','purple'), ('5.00','purple'), ('0.00','orange')
    , ('1.00','red'), ('0.00','blue'), ('0.00','blue')
    , ('3.00','red'), ('2.00','purple') --I added these values!

--The First non-zero randarfield per confis
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT confis, randarfield
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY confis ORDER BY ID) AS TheFirst
        FROM @BlueBonnet
        WHERE randarfield > 0
        ) Firsts
    WHERE TheFirst = 1
    )Results
PIVOT (MIN(randarfield) FOR confis IN([red],[purple])) AS pvt;

--The Min non-zero randarfield per confis
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT confis, MIN(randarfield) AS TheMin
    FROM @BlueBonnet
    WHERE randarfield > 0
    GROUP BY confis
    ) Results
PIVOT (MIN(TheMin) FOR confis IN([red],[purple])) AS pvt;

--The Max non-zero randarfield per confis
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT confis, MAX(randarfield) AS TheMax
    FROM @BlueBonnet
    WHERE randarfield > 0
    GROUP BY confis
    ) Results
PIVOT (MIN(TheMax) FOR confis IN([red],[purple])) AS pvt;
```

Also, there are **`blue`** and **`orange`** colours in your data. Should you be showing them too?